# Click a button using javascript via console in browser

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to click a specific button on a page using javascript by typing the javascript code into the chrome console. It doesn't work. Is it possible that the website can disable clicking an element via Javascript?

I've tried to call all buttons with a specific class to a variable and then used the .click() method on a specific point.

```
var zz = document.getElementsByClassName("red_buttons");
zz[0].click();
```

Ideally, this would cause the page to act in the same way as a regular mouse click (which actually works), but it does absolutely nothing as far as I know.

Comment: Check this: https://gomakethings.com/how-to-simulate-a-click-event-with-javascript/

Comment: hmm it's weird. I tried opening console in this page and do `var test = document.getElementsByClassName("s-btn");` followed by `test[0].click();` it will click the "Ask Question" button in this page (top right blue button). Maybe there's a typo in you class name? or can you do the same thing I did in this page in your console see if it works?

Comment: IE will ask you if you want to allow ActiveX after 1st console command and then works without problems. And that question is shown in browser...

Comment: your code is working as expected for me, can you check your classname you have in your button DOM?  <button class="red_buttons" />

Comment: there's no spelling mistake as people are suggesting. I believe the website I'm using it on has figured out a way to block a click in such a manner. 
Also, Thanks ZorgoZ, I will try your method and let you know if it works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code to click on a specific button on the page. In the elementId section, you should type the ID value of the button you want to click. You can desing the clickfunc() function in any flexibility you want. It will be enough for you to just type the button.click(). It will click basicly.

```
var button = document.getElementById('<ElementID>');

function sleep(ms) {
      return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
   }

async function clickfunc(){
    while(true){
        button.click();
        console.log("Tried. Next one in 10 sec.");
        await sleep(10000);
       }
  }

clickfunc();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible that the website can disable clicking an element via Javascript?

A script can use the [`isTrusted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted) property on an event to make a decision about whether the associated action should continue or not. This is commonly used to discriminate between authentic user input and automation. Here's the description from the linked MDN documentation:

> The `isTrusted` read-only property of the [`Event`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event) interface is a boolean value that is `true` when the event was generated by a user action, and `false` when the event was created or modified by a script or dispatched via [`EventTarget.dispatchEvent()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent).

---

It's possible to set this property to `true` in some script hosts (such as [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/)), but you can't (currently) do this in Chrome's dev tools console.